# Why can an injective function be an Submanifold?

Tags: manifolds, submanifold

For $2$ manifolds $M,N$ with dimension $m>n$, the analytical injective function $i:N\rightarrow M$ is called analytical embedding and $i(N)$ is called Submanifold.

From the definition of manifolds a function must be a Homeomorphism in order to be a manifold which means the function musst be a bijection (along with some other criterias).

So I don't understand why an injective function can be a Submanifold?

Comment: In general it is not.

Comment: If you want to read more about that, I recommend Chapter 4 in John Lee's book 'Introduction to Smooth Manifolds'. In particular the subsection on embeddings, where you will find an example of an injective smooth immersion whose image is not a submanifold. (and also a proof that it is a submanifold under the additional assumption that it is a homeomorphism onto it's image)